# How to force workbox to update file in the cache?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I configured my Workbox to cache images using "staleWhileRevalidate" strategy:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      new RegExp('\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg)'),
      workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'image_cache'
      })
    );
```

Now while it works fine in most cases, it will have a problem for a situation that user updates their avatar. My server updates user's avatar in the following manner:

1. the new avatar image will be uploaded to the server,
2. the server save the image to the same path and cover the previous user avatar
3. the server technology the client that the avatar is successfully updated

I did the following in my Java-script to handle avatar update:

```
update_avatar().then(()=>{
  window.location.reload(true)
})
```

This works fine without Workbox running in my local tests. But with Workbox, because that it will use the cached image, it will not be able to show the newest avatar when the users update their avatars. The users need to manually refresh the page twice to have the newer avatar show up, which is annoying.

I guess the simplest way is to save images to a new path on the server side but is there a good solution on the client side so I don't have to change the server structure.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this github (How to force a cache update of one file #1438)post](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1438)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thanks, I did come over that link before. For me, I already have the strategy for the avatar path. more importantly, I only want to force an update when the user updates his own avatar. I still want to use StaleWhileRetaliate strategy so that all the other users don't necessarily update the user avatar immediately (as desired), but the user who updates it himself should immediately see the changes. The trick is, the path of other users and this user when getting this avatar is the same, I have to force a cache update based on an event.